# Creating job instances concurrently causes MySQL deadlock using default isolation level?

Tags: spring-batch

Recently we run a test which created different Spring batch job instances concurrently (e.g 10 threads in parallel, job names are similar but different, e.g with the same prefix). And it's fairly easy to trigger deadlockerror reported from MySQL exception is

> org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:267) at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443) at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633) at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:862) at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:917) at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:922) at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:120) at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:140) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)

We searched for existing reports regarding to deadlock and find that some are specific to SQLServer like this: (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1448). After analysis of the isolation level used for creating jobs(SERIALIZABLE) and the operation sequence, we think the deadlock could be trigged as following:

1、before creating a job instance, the code will first query batch_job_instance table to check if the instance already exists(about 3 times), under SERIALIZABLE mode, this will hold shared next-key lock (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-next-key-locking.html) in MySQL which lock records that are in scope related to the job name.

2、thread 2 want to create job2 and insert a row in batch_job_instance and thread 3 want to do the same thing, as both threads hold the same read next-key lock and the rows that need to be inserted are also in the key scope, the deadlock will happen.

Refer to the link here(https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html#setIsolationLevelForCreate-java.lang.String-), we tried changing the isolation level to REPEATABLE_READ and this worked without any deadlock.

So the key question here is :

Is setting isolation level to REPEATABLE_READ the recommended solution here and is there any side effect of this solution as it's not set as default option ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we tried changing the isolation level to REPEATABLE_READ and this worked without any deadlock.

> So the key question here is : Is setting isolation level to REPEATABLE_READ the recommended solution here and is there any side effect of this solution as it's not set as default option ?

Yes, that's the way to go. If SERIALIZABLE is too aggressive, you can use a less aggressive isolation level for the job repository. That's why the `setIsolationLevelForCreate` is provided. This is actually documented in its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html#setIsolationLevelForCreate-java.lang.String-):

```
ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ would work as well
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, I am wondering if REPEATABLE_READ works well without deadlock and any other side effect, shall we consider to change this as the default option of Spring Batch,  any advantage of SERIALIZABLE VS REPEATABLE_READ here?

Comment: It should work, as documented. I believe SERIALIZABLE is the best default as we should, by default, try to prevent any concurrency issues, and then relax this constraint if a less aggressive level works as well.